# Is it possible to configure active directory and VPN on same Server 2019?

Tags: active-directory, vpn

I have an Active directory which configured on windows server 2019
could I on the same server configure a VPN?

Comment: Yes............

Comment: And that will not cause problems?
I read here that will cause many errors

https://serverfault.com/questions/354070/active-directory-and-vpn-on-single-server-setup

Comment: Technically, your question was whether or not it was possible - not whether or not it was a good idea.  Moreover, you didn't specify whether or not the "configure a VPN" was a VPN client or a VPN server - so the comment was accurate.

Comment: It can cause problems if you don't consider your DNS on your interfaces correctly.  The VPN interface must not register itself in DNS.

Comment: Everyone, when someone says "is it possible" re matters outside physics, they're generally asking whether it's a good idea, not looking for a binary yes/no response. "Is it a good idea?" is implicit in this question, but it's not difficult to understand the actual intent given basic reading comprehension skills.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Technically you can configure AD and VPN on same Windows Server instance. 
But such configuration is against all known Microsoft and community best practises. 
In age of virtualisation it makes no sense to host different roles inside one server instance. If you have only one physical host - install Hyper-V role and run two VMs, Windows Server Standard license allows it.